# div opacity not changing

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have some div's with images and text in them on a page, all with the same content:

```
<div class="indexThumb">
  <img src="img.jpg" />
  <div class="picWrapper">
    <p>some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and I am trying to animate the opacity via the jquery animate() function on page load but its not working.  Here is my javascript (i have included the latest jquery library):

```
$(function(){
  $('.indexThumb').animate({opacity:0.3}, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Which browser have you tried?

Comment: are you testing it in IE? it working here http://jsfiddle.net/yVNQx/

Comment: yeah i just tried chrome and it worked... why would firefox not support this?

Comment: Seems to be working in Firefox, as well. http://jsfiddle.net/yVNQx/ What version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be [working](http://jsfiddle.net/QyrB7/).

Comment: firefox 7.0.1 wont work for me, but viewing the exact same page in chrome works

Comment: @fridgerator Do you have noscript or similar running?

Comment: no i just installed firefox today, only addon i put on was firebug

Comment: @fridgerator Are you trying the fiddles we've posted here? Is there anything in the Firebug console?